# Error in query (1215) Cannot add foreign key constraint when trying to add to a flywheel db

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm trying to add a couple of tables for a some compatibility information i'm adding to a flywheel site and when I try to generate the table I'm getting "Error in query (1215) Cannot add foreign key constraint." which is sufficiently vague to keep me from knowing why. As far as I can tell based on my research my syntax is fine, and the table/column combo I'm adding as a Foreign key definitely exist. I'm fairly new to both mySQL and flywheel as a platform so It could be something very simple I'm just ignorant to and if that's the case I apologize

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
      `productsID` INT,
      `productName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `ios9` DOUBLE NULL,
      `ios10` DOUBLE NULL,
      `ios11` DOUBLE NULL,
      `ios12` DOUBLE NULL,
      `Notes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Android Compatible` BINARY NULL,
      `Web App Screen size` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Supported Browsers` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Web App Minimum Resolution` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Web App Aspect Ratio` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`productsID`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `ProductsID_UNIQUE` (`productsID` ASC),
      INDEX `compatibilityID_idx` (
        `ios9` ASC,
        `ios10` ASC,
        `ios11` ASC,
        `ios12` ASC
      ),
       FOREIGN KEY (`ios9`, `ios10`, `ios11`, `ios12`) REFERENCES `compatibilityValues` (
        `compatibilityId`,
        `compatibilityId`,
        `compatibilityId`,
        `compatibilityId`
      ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me sort this out!

turns out mySQL by default was trying to do all of the FK statements in one go (i used the visual designer) and flywheel wasn't liking that.

Breaking up the FK's like so made it work:

```
       FOREIGN KEY (`ios9`) REFERENCES `compatibilityValues` (
    `compatibilityId`  ) ,
   FOREIGN KEY (`ios10`) REFERENCES `compatibilityValues` (
    `compatibilityId`  ) ,
   FOREIGN KEY (`ios11`) REFERENCES `compatibilityValues` (
    `compatibilityId`  ) ,
   FOREIGN KEY (`ios12`) REFERENCES `compatibilityValues` (
    `compatibilityId`  )
```